# How I can get image full path from drawable in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please help me to get actual path of Image that is inside drawable in Android. I need this in Xamarin form.

Comment: Resources are not files and do not have files paths.  Forms is capable of dealing with image resources, why do you need a path?

Comment: Refer this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#Local_Images